# Suhosin changes

Tags: suhosin, ipb

I've recently purchased a virtual server in order to use it as a stage development for my site which is based on a forum script (ipb).

Problem is that before the installation and after it, ipb shows me some messages about suhostin limits. For example

```
'suhosin.post.max_vars' is 1000 and has to be changed to 4096
'suhosin.request.max_vars' is 1000 and has to be changed to 4096
```

For both occasions, it says that these settings are on my php.ini. After looking up, couldn't find any mention of suhosin there. But I found them at /etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini and I proceed and changed them with the correct values.

Problem is that I keep gettin the error messages and when I load phpinfo, I see that the old values are still there. I restarted apache, I even restarted the server but suhosin still has the old values even if I edit the suhosin.ini file and see my edits are there.

Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong ? I even added the lines to php.ini but still nothing changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a file called "php.ini" in your admin directory (you find this through the root where you have your forums) and put the following in. Change the values as needed.

```
suhosin.request.max_varname_length = 400
suhosin.get.max_value_length = 2000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 4100
suhosin.post.max_vars = 4100
```